# Show commits on detached head

Tags: git

If I do these steps:

1. git checkout mytag # I am on detached head now.
2. git commit
3. git commit

Which git command can be used to see the changes between mytag and the current state?

This command should not use "mytag", since it is not available any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `git merge-base`

```
git log `git merge-base HEAD master`..HEAD
```

`git merge-base` will give you the common ancestor between two branches.
Then `git log A..B` will give you the commit history from `A` to `B`

instead of `master` you can use the branch where `mytag` started from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git show
```

to view the changes introduced by the previous commit (the one where `HEAD` is currently pointing). You can also use `git show <COMMIT>` to view the changes introduced by any single commit you specify. (Details in the [`git show` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show).)

If you want to view the difference between two points, you can use

```
git diff <FROM> <TO>
```

where both `<FROM>` and `<TO>` refer to any commits (or references to commits, etc). (Details in the [`git diff` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).)

In your specific case, when you want to view the difference between the current commit and two commits ago, you can use

```
git diff HEAD~2 HEAD
```

where `HEAD~2` the 2nd-generation ancestor commit of `HEAD` (=where you currently are). This avoids using the refname of `mytag`, as you requested.

Details about the `<ref>~<n>` notation can be found in the [`gitrevisions` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).